# Not able to access a string value in aws lambda function from AWS API request

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created a sample AWS lambda function and integrated this function with AWS API.

I have written a post method in API and selected application/JSON whose request integration mapping is as below.

```
{
    'songTitle':"$input.params('songTitle')"
}
```

songTitle is being sent as parameter (application/JSON) with request to API.

However I am receiving $input.params() as empty.

As I am new to this I have no idea what is the correct way.

Please guide to access these params

Comment: Just pass in `{
    'songTitle': 'Some Random Song Titles'
}`

and you should be able to get the song titles by calling `event.songTitle`

Comment: @DylanLaw i tried the same. event.songTitle returns empty.

Comment: Maybe you can show us your lambda function and how you invoke the lambda function?

Comment: Lambda is as below:

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
    console.log('songTitle'+JSON.stringify(event.songTitle));
    var song = JSON.parse(event.songTitle);
 
    callback(null, song);
};

and body mapping template in api is as (application/json)

{
    'songTitle':"$input.params('songTitle')"
}

i am calling api using postman and method is POST

Comment: `event.songTitle` is a string. Not a JSON. If you run `console.log(event.songTitle);` you should get something you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your issue, but single quotes are not the same as double quotes in JSON. Anything in the mapping template that isn't escaped with the `$` character is written as-is in the actual payload.

Should be:

```
{
    "songTitle":"$input.params('songTitle')"
}
```

Edit: If that doesn't work, please also test by sending the Content-Type header in the request as application/json. If you don't send Content-Type at all, it should default to application/json mapping template.

Comment: I found solution, but posting here today. When we are reading values from body part of the request we should use different syntax. Use $input.path('$.key_from_request_body');

Answer (score 0):

In case of reading input parameters from request header part (for request integration mapping) 
syntax:

```
{
    'songTitle':"$input.params('songTitle')"
}
```

If we want to read parameters from request body part we should write as

```
{
    'songTitle':"$input.path('$.songTitle')"`enter code here`
}
```